# Using JavaScript Promises in APIs

Tags: javascript, promise

I am new to the concept of Promises in JavaScript. I have an app that offers APIs to other components.

**My Goal:** instead of using traditional callback based approach for asynchronous operation, I want to use Promises. I am presenting an example below:

```
requestCurrentPosition (correlationId, options)
```

Currently this is an async operation that passes a coorelation ID. When the operation completes, success or failure callback can be called:

```
failure(response, correlationId)
success(response, correlationId)
```

This API will now be refactored as below:

```
requestCurrentPosition (Promise, options)
```

Is this the correct approach? If yes, how will the callback function be notified?

Comment: Instead of passing the promise _into_ the function, _return_ it. The caller can then operate on it as per normal. It's how jQuery does it, among others. Actually, jQuery allows both passing a callback and it returns a promise, so you can use both with it. Thought that's more motivated for backwards compatibility, you don't really need both for a new API.

Comment: I think rather that requiring a `Promise` you would want to return the `Promise` and let the consumer decide how they will use it. See this [example](https://davidwalsh.name/promises) for ideas.

Comment: It's not clear from your example why you would be passing a promise into the function instead of a correlation ID. Could you clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach would be to return a promise:

```
var promise = requestCurrentPosition(options)
```

This allows for a usage like so:

```
requestCurrentPosition(...)
  .then(function(){...})
  .catch(function(){...});
```

Comment: Do I still need the correlation ID?

Comment: I don't excatly know what the ``requestCurrentPosition`` method does. But if it previously required the parameter to do it's work then yes, it still needs it.

Comment: requestCurrentPosition took two parameters, A globally unique identifier that is used to match client calls and options (position parameters). Assuming the operation executed successfully,  success() callback function would be called with corelationID. I think since we are returning Promise, we don't need corelation ID. Correct?

Comment: Ah okay, in this case yes. You can remove the correlationId. You can use the .then handler to react to 'success'. But you will still require the options parameter. I'll update my answer accordingly.